# Removing newline at the end of a register

Tags: vim

I'm trying to convert a linewise yanked register into characterwise. Problem is, using `:call setreg('"', @", 'v')` to make the unnamed register linewise leaves an "extra" newline at the end of the register. Is there any way to get rid of this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
:call setreg('"', substitute(@", "\n", "", ""), 'v')
```

Comment: If you do this often you may want to look into Ingo Karkat's [UnconditionalPaste](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3355) plugin

Comment: That will remove the first newline, not the trailing one.  I think either `:call setreg('"', @", 'v') | let @" = substitute(@", '\n$', '', '')` or `:call setreg('"', substitute(@", "\n$", "", ""), 'v')` will work.  Note that `'\n$'` and `"\n$"` are subtly different, but give the same result.

Comment: @benjifisher; Yes, this works, thank you very much! I was messing with substitute but couldn't get it quite right myself...

Accepting this answer  EDIT: @Peter Rincker; Yes, I'm actually using it, fantastic plugin. Was just in need of a permanent change.